# Fallo a la hora de la repetición del proceso

Tags: c

Me falla la segunda repetición, la que viene iniciada por un `if (c ='s')` , pido por favor que alguien intente solucionarlo.
muchas gracias

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char c,r;
    int letras = 0;
    int numeros = 0;
    printf("Lectura sucesiva de caracteres hasta leer 'q' ");
    printf("Comienza a introducir tus caracteres, sin espacios: ");

    do {
        scanf("%c", &c);
        if (c >= 97 && c <= 122)
            {
                 letras = letras + 1;
            }
        if (c >= 48 && c <= 57)
            {
                numeros = numeros + 1;
            }
    } while (c != 'q');

    letras = letras -1;
    printf("LA suma de todas las letras es: %i\n",letras);
    printf("La suma de todos los numeros es : %i\n",numeros);

    printf("Si quieres continuar pulsa 's', si no, pulsa otro caracter: ");
    scanf("%c",&c);

    if ( c = 's' )
        {
           do
           {
                printf("Comienza a escribir de nuevo tus caracteres: ");
                letras = 0;
                numeros = 0;

                do
                {
                     scanf("%c", &c);
                     if (c >= 97 && c <= 122)
                     {
                          letras = letras + 1;
                     }
                     if (c >= 48 && c <= 57)
                     {
                          numeros = numeros + 1;
                     }
                } while (c != 'q');

                letras = letras -1;
                printf("LA suma de todas las letras es: %i\n",letras);
                printf("La suma de todos los numeros es : %i\n",numeros);
                printf("Escribe 's' si quieres volver a realizar el proyecto, escribe otra letra para terminar: ");
                scanf("%c",&r);

          } while (c = 's');
       }
```

Comment: El problema es que no hace el bucle o que nunca entra?, podrías especificar mejor...

Comment: El fallo es que aunque le diga que se salga del bucle sigue metido y no sale

Comment: Intentaste lo que propuse?

Comment: `} while (c = 's');` Tu compilador podría haber sido un poco más generoso con las advertencias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

segun lo que entiendo , pasa lo siguiente

```
if ( c = 's' )
```

esta condición no surge efecto por que te falta un igual `=`, estaria correcto así:

```
 if ( c == 's' ),
```

que si es una **condición de comparación lógica**.

igualmente te pasa en `while (c = 's')`.

saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta cambiar el if por un while desde el comienzo y haz tu sentencia.
Adicional, en los condicionales no puedes usar un solo `=` debes usar los dos `==` para que sea válida como una condición para el compilador.
Algo como esto:

```
while (c == 's')
{
    printf("Comienza a escribir de nuevo tus caracteres: ");
    letras = 0;
    numeros = 0;

    do
    {
         scanf("%c", &c);
         if (c >= 97 && c <= 122)
         {
              letras = letras + 1;
         }
         if (c >= 48 && c <= 57)
         {
              numeros = numeros + 1;
         }
    } while (c != 'q');

    letras = letras -1;
    printf("LA suma de todas las letras es: %i\n",letras);
    printf("La suma de todos los numeros es : %i\n",numeros);
    printf("Escribe 's' si quieres volver a realizar el proyecto, escribe otra letra para terminar: ");
    scanf("%c",&r);

}
```